# How to write this SQL query in Django Models

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

I have a model Subjects

```
#models.py

class Subjects(models.Model)
    ....
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)
    ....
    number_of_followers = models.IntegerField( I want to have something like this: SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT name ) FROM school_subjects; )
```

I don't really know if I can do this inside IntegerField or I have to add this to save method.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Django book has answers to all sorts of these simple questions: http://djangobook.com/en/2.0/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this (using [`count()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count))?

```
Subjects.objects.all().count()
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct, BUT how can I update number_of_followers inside models.py? In other words, when the object gets created, I want this field to be field automatically.

Comment: So you want to save the total number of distinct `Subject` objects into the `number_of_followers` field of every `Subject` object? I think it would be better to just make a method that calculates that dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
school_subjects.objects.all().distinct('name').count()
```